# How to put an ArrayList to a map

Tags: java, arraylist, maps

I have a map and inside the map I have combination of maps and arraylists.
Example:

```
var genericMap={result=3,properties={key1=1, key2=2 ,key3= 3},errors=[Value1,Value2,Value3]}
```

The array list formed inside the map is dynamic.

I have to put the value of errors which is an Array List to a new map.
When i try using the code:
`linkedMap.putAll(genericMap.get("errors"))`

it gives an error:

```
org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: Can't find method java.util.HashMap.putAll(java.util.ArrayList).
```

Comment: Java and JavaScript are completely different languages. I've corrected your tags for you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please provide (much) more context for your question, and more relevant code. You're clearly using JavaScript in Java via the scripting API to either Rhino or Nashorn, for one thing, so tell us you're doing that, show us *how* you're doing it, etc.

Comment: @MikeC: In this specific case, both tags may be relevant. (Can't say for sure with the question as unclear as it currently is, but the OP appears to be using JavaScript in Java via the scripting API.)

Comment: I am using rhinoscript for my coding in the tool

Answer (score -1):

A map is based around key-value pairs, it looks like you are adding a list (value) to a map without a key.

Try:

```
linkedMap.put("errors", genericMap.get("errors"));
```

Comment: When i try using the above in my code i get the following error-org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: Can't find method java.util.HashMap.putAll(string,java.util.ArrayList).   Also i tried using linkedMap.put("errors",genericMap.get("errors") but it creates an empty arraylist inside the map, errors=[]